# How can I stop an image from moving and cause an action based on a keystroke?

Tags: javascript

I am teaching myself web programming.  I'm also working on C++.  I am having a problem with Javascript.

I need to know how to create an "if statement" based on the location of an image.

I am making a simple game that has a cannon that is moving back and forth.  I want the user to press a button that will cause the cannon to stop and fire launching another image toward the target.

I have already created the images and a gif of the image that will travel from the cannon in an arc toward the target.

If the user fires when the cannon is in the correct position the image will hit the target.

Can someone tell me how to create an if statement based on position?  Or can someone tell me how to make the cannon stop and make the gif appear?

Comment: Hi Garrett. Can you show us what you've done already, this will help show what level you're at, and give more information of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Take a look at this, it's a course that teaches JavaScript: http://www.codecademy.com

Answer (score 2):

To move the cannon, read up on the `onkeyup()` event - it will wait for when a key is released, and do something.

What will it do?  Probably change the `left` position of the cannon somehow. I'd recommend setting the CSS style `position:absolute` on your cannon, then changing the `.left` property with Javascript.

For example, here's some Javascript to get you started (untested):

```
var cannon = document.getElementById("cannonPic");
var leftlim = 200;

document.body.onkeyup = function() {
    // Remove 'px' from left position style
    leftPosition = cannon.style.left.substring(0, cannon.style.left - 2);

    // Stop the cannon?
    if (leftPosition >= leftLim) {
        return;
    }

    // Move cannon to new position
    cannon.style.left = cannon.style.left.substr(0, cannon + 10);
}
```

And its companion HTML would look like...

```
...
<img id='cannonPic' src='cannon.jpg' />
...
<script type='text/javascript' src='cannon.js' />
```

The HTML could be styled like this:

```
#cannonPic {
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

---

To answer your "appear/reappear" sub-question, you can use the `.display` property, accessed via Javascript:

```
var cannon = document.getElementById("cannonPic");

function appear() {
    cannon.style.display = '';
}

function hide() {
    cannon.style.display = 'none';
}
```

---

A small word of warning, things traveling in arcs will require some math to translate them in two dimensions, depending on how accurate you want it.  A fun exercise though if you like math :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the very first image on your page's x and y position on the screen, for instance, try:

```
var xpos = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].x;

var ypos = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little background, the way this is typically done:

1. You have a main loop that will "run" the game.
2. Each iteration of the loop, you a) update the positions of in-game objects (cannon, projectiles, and targets in your case) and b) render the resulting objects to the screen.
3. When you detect a "fire" keypress, you simply set the "speed" of your moving cannon to 0, causing it to "stop".

You can retrieve the object's position using Steve's or sajawikio's approach but your game logic determines (and should know) the position of all objects at all times. It is your game logic that says "draw the projectile at position (x,y)". Your game logic should NOT say "I have a projectile, not sure exactly where it is, HMM, so let's query it's position using Javascript". At least not in this case where you have simple, predictable movement.